# PropertySource optional override default with variable-named properties file

Tags: spring, properties-file, serenity-bdd

I have a Serenity-BDD project on IntelliJ with Serenity-Spring and multiple .properties files, one to show each deployment environment (dev, qa, production), with a base .properties file that contains the variables for localhost.

```
test.properties
test-dev.properties
test-qa.properties
test-prod.properties
```

I am passing an argument in my CLI command (-Denvironment) to select the .properties file that will override the base.

```
./gradlew build -Denvironment
```

In my @PropertiesSource, I have both files listed, with the environment variable for the override file:

```
@PropertySource(value = {"test.properties", "test-${environment}.properties"}, ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

However, when I run this locally through IntelliJ (Meaning no -Denvironment variable, meaning localhost, and wanting the test.properties file only), I get the following error in my output:

> INFO: Properties location [test-${environment}.properties] not resolvable: Could not resolve placeholder 'environment' in value "test-${environment}.properties"

What exactly is this error, and what is the best way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you hardcoded the fact that two properties files are loaded, I would go with Spring SpEL default value mechanism:

```
@PropertySource(value = {"test.properties", "test-${environment:local}.properties"})
```

This way, when no *environment* is available, Spring will load **test.properties** and **test-local.properties**.

It is normal that you have the **[test-${environment}.properties] not resolvable** error, as placeholders are resolved before `PropertySources` are loaded (which is logic if you think about it).

Besides, `ignoreResourceNotFound = true` is error prone, and I do not recommend using it in production code.

If you were to use only one file, you could go with

```
@PropertySource("${environment:local}.properties")
```

This is what will be loaded by Spring:

- => local.properties
- -Denvironment=uat     => uat.properties
- -Denvironment=prod   => prod.properties

Comment: Thanks for confirming that ignoreResourceNotFound is error prone; I didn't think it was working. Is there a better alternative? As test.properties is technically my local properties file, is there a way instead to ignore the second file if environment isn't provided? Or could I rename my test.properties to local.properties, remove the "test-" altogether, and have it override local.properties with local.properties again when no environment is provided?

Comment: Yes you can definitively use only one file and default its name: `@PropertySource(value = "${environment:test}.properties")`

Comment: @as.bealieu If you think this answer is satisfying for your problem, please mark it as so. Thanks in advance.